# Single Quote Causes Update SQL to Fail

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a user's email address as **d'anthony.fredrick@hotmail.com** and I use addslashes to make it **d\'anthony.fredrick@hotmail.com**, the following SQL statement fails.

`"UPDATE subscriptions SET sent = '1'  WHERE email ='" . $email . "'  Limit 1";`

The database as the email address is **d\'anthony.fredrick@hotmail.com**.  Why does the UPDATE fail?

Comment: Using prepared statements and parameter binding avoids this sort of problem completely. Both the MySQLi and PDO extensions offer this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `sent` = '1' WHERE `email` ='" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "' Limit 1";
```

note: mysql_* has been depreciated. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: You know the MySQL extension has been deprecated, right? See the warning at the [top of this page](http://www.php.net/manual/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: yeah, bad habits die hard. still trying to get used to it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Always, always, always escape strings before adding them to queries.

```
"UPDATE subscriptions SET sent = '1' WHERE email ='" . $dbconn->real_escape_string($email) . "' Limit 1";
```

If you're using the original mysql API then you'd use `mysql_real_escape_string` in place of `$dbconn->real_escape_string`

Comment: EXACTLY what I was about to say!

Comment: I would rather you say *"Always, always, always use prepared statements and parameter binding"*

Comment: @Phil My understanding is that prepared statements make more sense when you're running a similar query many times. What else are the benefits?

Comment: @Jasper Parameter binding (which is only available to a prepared statement) is the safest way to inject values into an SQL query. String escaping is not foolproof

Comment: @Phil Ah I hadn't read that before. I'll have to look into that. Thanks!